# Fetching Single Client Data - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my code below,

1. I request for the `ids` of selected products (by checking a checkbox).
2. Now, i find the clients of whom the products belong to. Then i get the name and phone number of the clients.
3. Now the `query string` below is an API to send messages to these clients.

but When i send a message, i am not able to seperate the product numbers for the respective clients.

For instance, if Mark and Bill are the clients, the message should be like

> Dear Customer, your products with number #343fr3 has been shipped - For Mark`
>
> Dear Customer, your products with number #22543 has been shipped - For Bill

But what happens with mine is, one clients (Mark or Bill) gets the product number of another in the message.

What am i doing wrong or could it be from how the api is structured?

```
 public function sendAll(Request $request)
 {
     $ids      = $request->ids; 
     $split    = explode(",",$ids);
     $shipment = Shipment::findOrFail($split);
     
     if(request()->ajax()) {
         $clients = Client::whereHas('products', function($find_clients)use($split)
        {
            $find_clients->whereIn('id',$split);
        })->get(); 
                        
        foreach($shipment as $check_shipment)
        {
            if($check_shipment->status == 0 )
            {
                //do something
            }
            else 
            {
                $get_client_name  = [];
                $get_client_phone = [];

                foreach($clients as $key => $client)
                {
                    $get_client_name[]  = $client->name;
                    $get_client_phone[] = $client->phone;
                }

                $query = "?key=something&to=".implode(',',$get_client_phone)."&msg=Dear Customer, your products with  number ".$check_shipment->id." has been shipped.";        
           }
       }         
   }
}
```

Comment: your question seems to be unclear to me

Comment: @kunal  what don't you understand please?

Comment: what is the relationship between the `Shipment` and the `Client`

Comment: client has many shipment @ChamaraAbeysekara

Comment: and a shipment belongs to a customer right?

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara exactly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the data you are trying to loop through doesn't not have a relationship between them. what you can do is,

```
 public function sendAll(Request $request)
 {  
  $ids      = $request->ids; 
  $split    = explode(",",$ids);
  $shipment = Shipment::with('client')->findOrFail($split);

   foreach($shipment as $check_shipment)
    {
      if($check_shipment->status == 0 )
     {
       //do something
     }
     else 
     {
       $get_client_name []= $check_shipment->client->name;
       $get_client_phone [] = $check_shipment->client->phone_no;                          
     }
   } 

 $query = "?key=something&to=".implode(',',$get_client_phone)."&msg=Dear Customer, your products with  number ".$check_shipment->id." has been shipped.";

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i would go moreless this way:

```
public function sendAll(Request $request)
{
 $ids = $request->ids; 
 $split = explode(",",$ids);
 $shipment = Shipment::where('status', '>', 0)->whereIn('id', $split);

 if(request()->ajax()) {

    foreach($shipment->get() as $check_shipment)
    {

            $query = "?key=something&to=".implode(',',$check_shipment->client->phone)."&msg=Dear Customer, your products with  number ".$check_shipment->id." has been shipped.";        

     }         
  }
}
```

I assume shipment belongs to client

Comment: In this case, if i select more than 4 client, will the query send message to all the 4 clients?

Comment: have you tried this `implode(',',$check_shipment->client->phone)` ? this will return an error. `implode()` need an array and `$check_shipment->client->phone` won't return an array

Comment: cos this is collection, easy fix use `collect($check_shipment->client->phone)->toArray()` instead

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara, it doesn't return an error. `implode(',',$check_shipment->client->phone)` has been working fine always